# Simplify $O(n^k/2^n)$

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

In one of my complexity analysis, I came up with $O(n^k/2^n)$, where $k$ is a fixed number and $n$ is the size of the data. However I rarely see a big-O written as this. Is there a way to even further simplify this complexity in terms of $n$ and $k$ that I miss? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is $o(1)$.

Comment: Although this is $o(1)$, $o(1)$ is certainly not equivalent to this. $O(n^k/2^n)$ is a much stronger statement than $o(1)$.

Comment: Yeah I agree with TMM. Though it is $O(1)$ but $O(n^k/2^n)$ tells us how the complexity behaves in terms of $n$ and $k$. I was thinking if there are ways to express $O(n^k/2^n)$, still in terms of $n$ and $k$, in even simpler forms. Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: @ELW: $O(n^k/2^n)$ already looks pretty specific, especially if you want to keep the $k$ in there. I don't think there's an even cleaner form for this...

Comment: @TMM I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** Do you know that $$\frac{n^k}{2^n}\to 0$$ for any $k$?